# In LaTeX internals, what is `\protected@file@percent`? How is it used, and what for?

Tags: auxiliary-files

A version upgrade has broken some of my tools, which are finding `\protected@file@percent` in `.aux` files and in table-of-contents lines.  I've looked at `latex.ltx` but have not figured out how this control sequence is used or what it is for.  Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: There is a documented version of the latex sources that you can read with the command `texdoc source2e`. That will open a pdf file `source2e.pdf`. You can find an explanation there. Search for the command name in the pdf file; in the version found on the latest tex live, it's on page 273.

Comment: The command should hide spaces at the end of the lines in the toc - in some cases this spaces appeared in the output. See https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/73